Cefsharp Open Tabs Offscreen
So I'm working on a VR app in csharp and I need to either open multiple offscreen browsers, which i have tried to do by instantiating this class:
public class Browser {

    public ChromiumWebBrowser browserInstance;

    public string Url { get => browserInstance == null ? url : browserInstance.Address; set { url = value; if (browserInstance != null) browserInstance.LoadUrl(url); } }
    private string url;

    public Browser(string url) {
        Url = url;
#if ANYCPU
        CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver();
#endif
        Init();
    }

    public async Task Init() {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings {
            UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.79 Mobile Safari/537.36",
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
        };

        await Cef.InitializeAsync(settings, performDependencyCheck : true, browserProcessHandler : null);
        browserInstance = new ChromiumWebBrowser(Url);
        await browserInstance.WaitForInitialLoadAsync();
    }

    // this is used to paint the browser on a texture elsewhere in the project
    public void BindPaintEvent(EventHandler<OnPaintEventArgs> action) { 
        browserInstance.Paint += action;
    }
}

When I do so, the ChromiumBrowsers do not initialize, I read somewhere that this was because there can only be a single instance of a Chromium Browser per App.
So what I am now trying to do is to open multiple tabs of this one browser and paint each of them individually.
But I can't seem to find how to do that... What do you think I could do?
(Yes I have done my research, no I haven't found anything relevant to my issue).

Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4861 Please just ask your question once and wait for a reply before asking in multiple places.
